# sql charindex extract number from string

Tags: sql, charindex

I have a column called original_filename which contains text. within the text there is a file ID which I want to extract. The description starts with "error_rows_" as shown below. However the file ID's vary in length i.e 999 to 999999 followed by additional text.

```
 error_rows_90349_2014-04-10_00-00-00_Transaction-Login_TheHut.gpg
 error_rows_904003_2014-04-10_12-00-00_Transaction-Login_TheHut.gpg
 error_rows_90403_2014-04-10_12-00-00_Transaction-Registration_TheHut.gpg
 error_rows_9060_2014-04-11_00-00-00_Transaction-Login_TheHut.gpg
```

Can someone help me with the sql to extract this. the end result should be:

90349
904003
90403
9060

I have been trying to use charindex withou success

Comment: "I have been trying to use charindex withou success" -- Then please show your attempts.

Comment: select left (original_filename, CHARINDEX ('_', original_filename, 12)-1), *
from monitor_files
where original_filename like 'error_rows_%'

Comment: No not in comments.  Update your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (TestData VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @Test SELECT 'error_rows_90349_2014-04-10_00-00-00_Transaction-Login_TheHut.gpg';
INSERT INTO @Test SELECT 'error_rows_904003_2014-04-10_12-00-00_Transaction-Login_TheHut.gpg';
INSERT INTO @Test SELECT 'error_rows_90403_2014-04-10_12-00-00_Transaction-Registration_TheHut.gpg';
INSERT INTO @Test SELECT 'error_rows_9060_2014-04-11_00-00-00_Transaction-Login_TheHut.gpg';
SELECT
    *,
    CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TestData, 12, CHARINDEX('_', TestData, 12) - 12))
FROM
    @Test;
```

Results:

```
90349
904003
90403
9060
```

Comment: I also used this bit ,RIGHT(left(original_filename, CHARINDEX ('_', original_filename, 12)-1), LEN(left(original_filename, CHARINDEX ('_', original_filename, 12)-1)) - CHARINDEX ('_',left(original_filename, CHARINDEX ('_', original_filename, 12)-1), 7) ) [FileID]